# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' : attempt to scroll to invalid index path

Tags: ios, exception, uicollectionview

This is my code for animating the CollectionViewCustomCells.

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{

    rowIndex = 0;

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0
                                     target:self
                                   selector:@selector(targetMethod)
                                   userInfo:nil
                                    repeats:YES];
}

-(void)targetMethod
{
    [self.offerCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:rowIndex inSection:1]
                      atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                              animated:YES];

    rowIndex=(rowIndex<parserDataContentArrayForExhibitor.count-1)?(rowIndex+1):0;

//    if (rowIndex == parserDataContentArrayForExhibitor.count) {
//        rowIndex = 0;
//    }


}


Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath 0xab55110> 2 indexes [1, 0]'
```

I am getting this exception each time i run my app. **But sometimes the app is running good.**
I believe there is some leak or something kind of stuff.
What I tried : When i googled I Found that this kind of error is because if i write a section which does not exist and the section's index is 0 for the first section.

so i changed my target method to :

```
-(void)targetMethod
{
    [self.offerCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:rowIndex inSection:0]
                      atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                              animated:YES];

    rowIndex=(rowIndex<parserDataContentArrayForExhibitor.count-1)?(rowIndex+1):0;

//    if (rowIndex == parserDataContentArrayForExhibitor.count) {
//        rowIndex = 0;
//    }


}
```

But then the same thing happens with a slight change in the parameter of the exception.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath 0xab22ea0> 2 indexes [0, 0]'
```

Section Code:

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView{

    return 1;
}
```

PLease help me as this is kind of new to me.

Thank You.

Best Regards.

Comment: How many sections do you have? Sections start at index 0.

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg : I have just one section.

Comment: `inSection=0` is fine. The problem might be with `rowIndex`.

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg : So do i need to change rowIndex to 1 or probably write it in VDL or in any other method as such ???

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg : and my main concern is, this thing is happening only sometimes and the app runs smoothly sometimes !!!

Comment: That definitely means some undefined behaviour. Try to NSLog `[self.offerCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section];` and check the output.

Comment: @nikhitadkslfslg : Whne i log it in target method what i get is 
              [self.offerCollectionView numberOfItemsInSection:section] =8.
each time the cell animates.

Comment: How mane rows are in the collection when it doesn't work? How do you check the index path exists?

Comment: @Wain : Probably the condition Hercules has suggested is working great !!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Keep this line inside an `if`:

```
if (parserDataContentArrayForExhibitor.count > 0) {
 rowIndex = (rowIndex<parserDataContentArrayForExhibitor.count - 1) ? (rowIndex + 1) : 0;
}
```

Since you are passing a section count of 1, keep your section 0 and not 1 because the indexing is zero based. If you had numberOfSectionsInCollectionView = 2 then you could have two sections `{0, 1}`

```
[self.offerCollectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath: [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem: rowIndex inSection: 0];
                  atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewScrollPositionCenteredHorizontally
                          animated:YES];
```