# Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException, reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path

Tags: ios, swift

I am adding a `UICollectionView` in `UITableviewCell`, and then adding this code to animate my `UICollectionViewCell`:

```
let CardCollectionCellId = "CardCollectionCell"
let SlideShowTimeInterval = TimeInterval(7)

protocol CardCellDelegate {
    func didSelectCard(card:Card)
}

class CardTableViewCell: UITableViewCell,UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout{

    var category:CardCategory!

    var delegate: CardCellDelegate!

    var slideShow = true

    @IBOutlet weak var overlayView: UIVisualEffectView!

    @IBOutlet weak var collectionView:UICollectionView!

    func configureCell(){

    collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "CardCollectionCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: CardCollectionCellId)

    initialzeTimerForCategory(category: category)

    collectionView.reloadData()
}


// TODO:Ideally It should run when cell is visible
func initialzeTimerForCategory(category:CardCategory){

    if category.isSlideShowOn && slideShow {

            var rowIndex = 0
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: SlideShowTimeInterval, repeats: true) { (Timer) in

                let items = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0)

                if items > 0{
                    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: rowIndex, section: 0), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.centeredHorizontally, animated: false)

                    rowIndex = rowIndex < (items - 1) ? (rowIndex + 1) : 0

                }
                print("=========>",items,rowIndex)

            }
        }

}


// MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.category.cards.count
}


func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let card = self.category.cards[indexPath.row]
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: CardCollectionCellId, for: indexPath) as! CardCollectionCell

    cell.configureCell(card: card)
    return cell

}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    self.delegate.didSelectCard(card: self.category.cards[indexPath.row])
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width
    return CGSize(width: width - 20, height: 350)

}
```

}

Code is working fine when I don't scroll the table, but when I scroll the table then it crashes and throw this error :

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'attempt to scroll to invalid index path: <NSIndexPath: 0x600000231aa0> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}'
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['NSInvalidArgumentException' : attempt to scroll to invalid index path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18201409/nsinvalidargumentexception-attempt-to-scroll-to-invalid-index-path)

Comment: I think your missing some code that would make it easier to spot the issue, can you show how you populate the data source?

Comment: That error is usually because it's trying to scroll to something that doesn't exist, so a indexpath that isn't there

Comment: @bolnad updated my complete code, I know this issue occur when we try to scroll for an indexpath that does not exist.

Comment: @dirtydanee, I have already explored that question but the solution of that question did not help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after looking at the code that you have provided it looks like your trying to autoscroll a collectionview on a UITableView.  This appears to happen when you populate a cell of the UITableView by calling `configureCell` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

What it looks like is happening is when you scroll the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called on each cell you scroll through, there by triggering `configureCell`.  Inside `configureCell` you configure a Timer to start repeating the animations.

I don't see where you ever invalidate that timer or stop it once you are done with that cell.

you could test this theory out by commenting out the timer and seeing if the problem goes away.

If it is this issue, then the easiest way to fix this is implement the `prepareForReuse()` method of the UITableViewCell and invalidate the timer.

here's the Apple documentation to [prepareForReuse](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell/1623223-prepareforreuse)